# how to get only folder path name without file name using file upload control in Ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

Is any other way to get the slected folder path other than using fileupload control ?

using file upload control i am getting filename but i need to get only selected folder path , is it possible to get folder path ?

Code:

```
<input id="fileToUpload" type="file" size="45" style="width:300px;" name="fileToUpload" onChange="addFiles(this, this.value,this.value);" class="input">

<select name="mcffiles" id="mcffiles" size=5 style="width:200px; height:100px">

function addFiles(selectObject, seltext, selvalue)
    {   
         alert(seltext);
         alert(selvalue);
        var optionObject = new Option(seltext,selvalue);
        var optionRank = document.getElementById("mcffiles").options.length;
        alert(optionRank);
        if(optionRank <= 4)
        {
            document.getElementById("mcffiles").options[optionRank]= optionObject;
        }
        else
           alert('Only 5 files can select')

    }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Rails? Looks like Javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you mean the folder path on the client then no, javascript can not access the local file system even to read.

If you want to allow upload of the entire folder content (which I guess is why you are asking), then you have to embed flash or something similar.

Comment: i want browse folder path and need to use that path for move file from other location to selected folder path . this is my requirement...

Comment: Okay, I'm still not sure what you're after. You want to browse a folder path on Server or Client? To move a file from other location on Server or Client?

Comment: File upload control will open File open dialog and will display full path in input box but i need same functionality for open folder dialog and need to display path(Only path)--- It's fully client side .